# Can 16,000 volt with around 3.5 to 5 amps be enough to heat a wire to 1400F

Tags: high-voltage, pressure

If i push 16,000V through a nichrome 10 gage wire with only 3.5 to 5 amps csn that pressure be enough to heat the wire up to 1400F

Comment: That's 80kW! You might evaporate the wire.

Comment: One word, plasma.............

Comment: Do i need to go for a larger gage wire?

Comment: @RoyC what do you mean exactly?

Comment: You need to go for considerably less volts. Power is volts squared divided by the resistance of your bit of wire. How hot it will get depends on the power and the wires ability to lose heat to the environment. What I meant was putting that voltage on a piece of nichrome will give you an extreme heating event.

Comment: Maybe you should start at the beginning. Describe your setup (for instance, is the voltage/current constant, or is it a charged capacitor, or what?). As pjc50 pointed out, you're talking about 80 kW, which is about 8 times the power used by an average US home, and you don't seem to have any clue what that means. So start at the beginning, and tell us what you have, what you want to do, and why. Also, note that a 60 watt incandescent bulb has a filament temperature in the range of 2500 C, which is about 4500 F.

Comment: Please film the resultant fire.

Comment: Well what im trying to do for a Project is have my go kart im building run off electric heating instead of gas. " I could make it like an electric car and use the electricity to power it but that will push my budget way over" so i wanted to have the set up of an internal combustion engine but replace the gas with an electric heating element to reach high temp. I was going to use a car battery and ignition coil and as i read they can reach volts up to 16,000 and only have around 3.5 5 amps moving through it. I dont think the amps will be enough as is.

Comment: I think you should try it with 16000 Volts and 5 Amps current.  That could be a good YouTube video of what not to do with electricity.

Comment: Lol point take. What if i stepped it down to around 30 or 60V?

Comment: The numbers are all wrong here - you may have 16000 Volts but is it actually capable of putting 5A through a wire? (an 80kW supply?) That would require your wire to have a resistance of 3200 ohms. That's a huge length of nichrome wire.  You don't push voltage anywhere - voltage is across the load, current is through the load. Ohm's law applies.

Comment: What do you mean by 'electric heating instead of gas'?

Comment: Well i can increase amps but car battery only have around 45 amp hours and i want the lowest amps possible to reach my heating needs

Comment: Using electricity to heat air in the cylinders in place of a fuel explosion is a bad plan. Your efficiency will be **awful**. If you want to make an electric vehicle, then a motor is the way to go.

Comment: I understand that colin.. Its a fun little project to improve skills. As you see i need more learning to do. Thats kind of all. Not trying to make a new hot engine lol. But i see your point.

Comment: Far better to use the electricity to make hydrogen and oxygen and run the engine on that.

Comment: You have badly misunderstood ignition coils. 5 amps refers to the input, while 16,000 volts refers to the output. Output current will be on the order of 4 mA (average), for a total power dissipation of about 60 watts. Your project, I am afraid, is doomed to failure as long as you try to do it this way. Driving electric motors is your only real hope. If you need more power, you need a bigger battery.

Comment: Think about it this way. You have an ignition coil and you want to heat up a wire with the energy you can get out of the coil. Rather than use a wire, use a spark plug. The energy from the coil will give you a nice blue spark with just as much energy as you intend to put into the wire. It will heat up the air to just the same extent.  Now, how fast will your go kart go with just the spark plug (but no gasoline)?

Comment: You've already had it explained why this is a terrible idea at https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/41731/why-arent-electric-forms-of-heating-used-in-internal-combustion-engines

Answer (score 2):

What I understood from the comments what you want to do:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYvXgq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(Values are not to scale)

This is a standard car ignition, with a resisitor instead of a spark plug.
Lets say an ignition coil can indeed push 80kW (16.000 V*5 A), which is realisitic. So every spark releases how much energy:

80 kW * 400 nS = 0,032 Joules

At 4000 rpm you get 66 sparks per second.

0,032 mJ * 66 = 2,11 Joules

So if you can reach 100% efficency, you get 2,11 Watts out of your engine.
That's going to be a very fun drive for your go kart.

If you step down to 120V at 100% efficency, you get 667 A for 400nS.

120 V * 667 A * 400 nS = 2,11 Joules

So that did nothing for you. Please note that 100% is not achivable and real results will be much worse. Also you will encounter engineering problems.

Comment: Base on what others say 16,000 is far to much so let's go way lower. Will 120V with around 5A be enough to heat the nichrome wire to 1400F?

Comment: @DeusIIXII, that will be 100x less power, so 20 mW, if you use it the same way. If you continuously deliver 5 A at 120 V, that's 600 W...about 0.8 hp.

Comment: If there were an obvious cheaper way than batteries and electric motors to power a vehicle (even a small one like a golf cart), don't you think the car and golf cart companies would already be using it?